# Sending a confirmation mail for an e-mail address change to the old address

Tags: email

Is there a point in sending a confirmation mail to the old address? I see two points there

- If your account is taken over, a confirmation mail to the old address with an *undo* link would revert the take over.
- If your e-mail address is taken over, you cannot change the mail address on the service as the attacker can cancel the request.

The first point would be a big benefit for the security on the service. The problem is, that the second point makes the life for someone with a hacked e-mail account even harder.

Comment: MFA (Mutli-factor authentication)  is a better way to approach such issue.  It create second layer of security (although it doesn't mean it is 100% bullet proof)